# What is the use of public constructor in nested class

Tags: java, nested

I have seen a bunch of places where we have public constructors in nested classes.
The question is why / when would you need them ? It appears that a private constructor would also appear to do the same job, so why dont we have a convention that any inner / nested class requires private constructors ?

If we never need to construct inner class outside the object, is it right thing to declare inner class constructor private ? If so then why does Entry in java maps not declare its constructor private?

Thanks,

Comment: See `java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`. It's a nested class with public constructors, isn't it? If it's constructors are private we can't use the class.

Comment: Are you happy with my answer? If so then you should accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you wouldn't be able to instantiate the inner class from anywhere else.
Being able to instantiate the inner class is heavily used in the Builder Pattern:

```
House house = new House.Builder().addRoof().paint(Color.WHITE).build();
```

If the constructor of Builder was private, you wouldn't be able to do the above which is very useful when building objects with complex state.